# Exposing service from Kubernetes NGINX Ingress controller always return 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, websocket, digital-ocean, nginx-ingress

I am having issues with request to my NodeJS app running in my kubernetes cluster in digital ocean. Every request returns a `502 Bad Gateway Error`. I am not sure what I am missing.

This is what the service config looks like

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name:  service-api
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app:  service-api
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    app:  service-api
```

The Ingress.yml looks like this

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: service-api-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-connections: '2'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rpm: '60'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-protocol: "http"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-algorithm: "round_robin"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-http2-ports: "443,80"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-tls-ports: "443"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-tls-passthrough: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - dev-api.service.com
    secretName: service-api-tls
  rules:
  - host: "dev-api.service.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: service-api
            port:
              number: 80
```

Whenever I visit the host url I get a 502 error.

This is what appears in the nginx ingress log

```
2021/01/13 08:41:34 [error] 319#319: *31338 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: IP, server: dev-api.service.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://10.244.0.112:3000/favicon.ico", host: "dev-api.service.com", referrer: "https://dev-api.service.com/status"
```

Comment: Can you share netstat -plant output table ?

Comment: @Malgorzata I am not sure how to do that in kubernetes. but from the log it appears that the internal IP in the request `10.244.0.112` does not match the cluster IP of the service.

Comment: Simply execute this command in node command line netstat -plant. Also provide output of your Nginx Configuration: $ kubectl exec -it -n <namespace-of-ingress-controller> <nginx-ingress-controller-pod> -- cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Comment: @Malgorzata You can find it here https://gist.github.com/EmmanuelAmodu/519d87b1efb7c9a4c9e00a2a6aa2a7c9

Comment: Can you also paste output of command $ kubectl describe svc service-api ?

Comment: I updated the gist with the result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227281/discussion-between-malgorzata-and-emmanuel-amodu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we ( with @Emmanuel Amodu ) have discussed in comment:

mistake was to connect to app using wrong port, port `4000` instead of `3000` as defined in `service-api`.

For community which will have similar problem please - most important steps for debugging:

1. Checking netstat -plant output table
2. Checking your Nginx Configuration: `$ kubectl exec -it -n <namespace-of-ingress-controller> <nginx-ingress-controller-pod> -- cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
3. Checking service: `$ kubectl describe svc service-api`

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the annotation that configures SSL passthru?

If SSL passthru has been configured on your ingress controller then your service needs to expose port 443 in addition to port 80. You're basically saying the pod is terminating the secure connection not nginx.

If this is the issue would explain 50X error which indicates a problem with the backend

Comment: I am not sure that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

No special setup is needed, that 404 is most likely coming from your actual backend.

Comment: true but on my local machine websocket connects fine.